# Animation in custom pager in not starting up

Tags: android

I have a custom pager that uses two animations

```
final Animation fadeOut = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(mContext, R.anim.fade_out);
final Animation fadeIn = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(mContext, R.anim.fade_in);
```

For some reason, the animations are not starting up. For example, I'm logging

```
Log.v("TAG", "L1 start animation"); //prints "L1 start animation"
```

But I'm not logging anything in `onAnimationEnd`

```
Log.v("TAG", "L1 animation end"); //nothing is printing out
```

Here is `setAnimation()` method of `CustomPager` class

```
 public void setAnimation(){

    final Animation fadeOut = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(mContext, R.anim.fade_out);
    final Animation fadeIn = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(mContext, R.anim.fade_in);

    l1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Log.v("TAG", "L1 clicked");

            if (clicked) {

                //do nothing

            } else {

                clicked = true;

                fadeOut.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
                        Log.v("TAG", "L1 animation start");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                        Log.v("TAG", "L1 animation end");
                        l1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        l2.bringToFront();
                        clicked = false;

                    }
                });
                Log.v("TAG", "L1 start animation");
                l1.startAnimation(fadeOut);
                l2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                l2.startAnimation(fadeIn);
            }
        }
    });

    //etc

}
```

Here is `CustomPager` class

```
public class CustomPager extends PagerAdapter {

    private Context mContext;
    private View l1;
    private View l2;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private ViewGroup layout;
    private Bitmap pic;
    private Bitmap pic_blurred;
    private boolean clicked = false;

    public CustomPager(Context context) {

        this.mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup collection, int position) {

        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
        layout = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.pager_play_panel, collection, false);
        collection.addView(layout);

        l1 = layout.findViewById(R.id.l1);
        l2 = layout.findViewById(R.id.l2);

        pic = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mContext.getResources(), R.drawable.pic);
        picture_blurred = blur(pic, 1, 100);

        BitmapDrawable bkg1 = new BitmapDrawable(pic);
        l1.setBackgroundDrawable(bkg1);

        BitmapDrawable bkg2 = new BitmapDrawable(picture_blurred);
        l2.setBackgroundDrawable(bkg2);

        setAnimation();

        return layout;
    }

    public void setAnimation(){

        final Animation fadeOut = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(mContext, R.anim.fade_out);
        final Animation fadeIn = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(mContext, R.anim.fade_in);

        l1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Log.v("TAG", "L1 clicked");

                if (clicked) {

                    //do nothing

                } else {

                    clicked = true;

                    fadeOut.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
                            Log.v("TAG", "L1 animation start");
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                            Log.v("TAG", "L1 animation end");
                            l1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            l2.bringToFront();
                            clicked = false;

                        }
                    });
                    Log.v("TAG", "L1 start animation");
                    l1.startAnimation(fadeOut);
                    l2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    l2.startAnimation(fadeIn);
                }
            }
        });

        l2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Log.v("TAG", "L2 clicked");

                if (clicked) {

                    //do nothing

                } else {

                    clicked = true;

                    fadeOut.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {

                            l2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            l1.bringToFront();
                            Log.v("TAG", "L2 visibility set to gone");
                            clicked = false;


                        }
                    });
                    l2.startAnimation(fadeOut);
                    l1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    l1.startAnimation(fadeIn);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    //Etc.
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the problem was I had to change the scope of my view variables

```
public void setAnimation(View l1, View l2){ 

    //etc
}
```

Rather than using them globally

```
public void setAnimation(){ 

    //etc
}
```